# How to manage properties and secret values in Dataflow Java pipelines?

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, configuration, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have some Dataflow pipelines written in Java that run on GCP in different environments/projects (development, UAT, production). Currently, the environment configuration (mainly connection parameters for Cloud SQL instances and BigQuery datasets) is managed using a static map in a Java class (key = env, value = map of properties) and an utility class to dynamically load additional files from Cloud Storage.

What are the best practices (if any) for managing the configuration in such a context?

Essentially, I see two kinds of configuration parameters:

- plain values (something that in a Spring application you'd store in a plain property file)
- secret values (property files containing data that must be encrypted - username/password for a database, API keys - something that in a K8S context can be mounted as Secret)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will find this tutorial helpful on how to [Access Secret Manager from Dataflow Pipeline](https://henrysuryawirawan.com/posts/dataflow-secret-manager/)

> "As of today, Dataflow does not provide native support for storing and
> accessing secrets. To secure those secrets, the common approach is to
> use Cloud KMS to encrypt the secret and decrypt it when running the
> data pipeline. With the newly launched Secret Manager, we can now
> store those secrets in Secret Manager and access them from our
> pipeline to provide better security and ease of use."

The following code uses Secret Manager SDK to access the secret given a JDBC URL secret name.

```
private static String jdbcUrlTranslator(String jdbcUrlSecretName) {
  try (SecretManagerServiceClient client = SecretManagerServiceClient.create()) {
    AccessSecretVersionResponse response = client.accessSecretVersion(jdbcUrlSecretName);

    return response.getPayload().getData().toStringUtf8();
  } catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Unable to read JDBC URL secret");
  }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  PipelineOptionsFactory.register(MainPipelineOptions.class);

  MainPipelineOptions options =
      PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args)
          .withValidation()
          .as(MainPipelineOptions.class);

  NestedValueProvider<String, String> jdbcUrlValueProvider =
      NestedValueProvider.of(
          options.getJdbcUrlSecretName(), MainPipeline::jdbcUrlTranslator);

  Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);

  pipeline
      .apply("SQL Server - Read Sales.Customers_Archive",
          JdbcIO.<KV<Integer, String>>read()
              .withDataSourceConfiguration(
                  JdbcIO.DataSourceConfiguration.create(
                      StaticValueProvider.of("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"),
                      jdbcUrlValueProvider)
              );
  
  // Other transforms

  pipeline.run();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to handle to handle secret values inside the Google Cloud Platform is using the Secret Manager handling the encryption and access control to the stored passwords.

Inside your Java code you can use the [Google Cloud Secret Manager](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.cloud/google-cloud-secretmanager) maven module to get the sotred secret values